# Write a query that pulls all fields from a table that has date in it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, stored-procedures, select

I have table with about 100+ fields. There are a number of date fields in it scattered around (I am suspecting about 8 or more). I would like to have a query or StoredProcedure that selects only those fields whose data type is Date or Datetime.

This is not a requirement from Project, it will only be my analysis tool.

I am using MSSQL 2005 but it does not have to be only in MSSQL.

Comment: So all the columns are varchars and you want to scan the table for values in those columns that might look like a date?

Comment: No. If a column is defined as datetime field (not by actual name), only those column need to be shown or even selected is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'yourTableName'
and data_type like '%date%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query the metadata:

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'yourtable'
and data_type in ('datetime', 'smalldatetime')
```

Also, this `information_schema.columns` is available in other database systems.